# How to select same table in update statement with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In this table, there is a column called 'position'. This column counts up from 0. (First row has position 0, second has 1 etc.)

Now, if the row with position 4, moves up, I want to set the row above (row with position 3) to the current position. (So position 3 becomes position 4.)

So for example:

I have:

```
id = 12, position = 2
id = 11, position = 3
id = 9, position = 4
id = 8, position = 5
```

After the update I want:

```
id = 12, position = 2
id = 11, position = 4
id = 9, position = 3
id = 8, position = 5
```

I want to use the id of the row, to update the position.

This is what I've got, but it doesn't work on MySQL:

```
UPDATE message
SET position = position + 1
WHERE position = (SELECT position - 1 FROM message WHERE id = 11);
```

When I try to run it, it gives me this error: 'SQL Error(1093): You can't specify target table 'message' for update in FROM clause'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what does "it doesn't work on MySQL" mean exactly ? any error messages or does just not do what you expect ? please elaborate with some sample data

Comment: this is a known issue... try my answer below (not sure that it works though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - after UPDATE with sample data from OP:

I assume you know the ID (=11) and want the data to change as illustrated in your updated question... you need to update 2 rows to achieve that:

```
UPDATE message m SET
m.position = (CASE WHEN m.id = 11 THEN m.position + 1 ELSE m.position - 1 END)
WHERE m.id = 11 OR m.id =
(SELECT z.li FROM (SELECT MAX (l.id) li FROM message h INNER JOIN message l ON h.position = (l.position - 1) WHERE h.id = 11) z);
```

Comment: SQL Error (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

When i try `(SELECT * FROM message) AS x`, it runs but it doesn't affect anyting.

Comment: @Yahia Wrapping it twice is not going to help.

Comment: @Ivar that means the problem is "technically" solved (MySQL error)... the part about "0 rows updated" means that the logic isn't right i.e. the WHERE clause(s) need to be different... as I wrote in my comment: show some sample data and "before/after" (i.e. desired result)

Comment: @Yahia Yah, that works! Pretty inefficient though selecting the whole table that way - you don't have to do that. To my surprise wrapping it twice does help!

Comment: @Ivar see my EDIT above... this should give you the desired result now (2 rows affected)...

Comment: @Ariel checkout the new one (after the OP posted sample data)... this should be rather efficient...

Comment: @Ariel, wrapping a sub-select twice **does** help the cannot select from the same table in an update issue. **because it forces MySQL to materialize the subselect in a temp-table** thereby decoupling the subselect from the table that's being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY position DESC` to the query to do it from the bottom up and avoid having the same position twice at the same time.

Edit: I posted this before the OP said what his error was - I just guessed.

By far the simplest solution here is just get the position in the parent code, and don't do in in MySQL.

Comment: @Yahia I posted this before the OP posted what the error was. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Think we need to follow this through (I think I've understood the idea, but correct me if not):

Consider two rows:

Before row change

```
ID=10, Position=3
ID=11, Position=4
```

We move ID=11 up:

```
ID=10, Position=3
ID=11, Position=3
```

We need

```
ID=10, Position=4
ID=11, Position=3
```

Therefore the update should be:

```
UPDATE message
SET position = position + 1
WHERE position = (SELECT position FROM (select id, position from message) WHERE id = 11)
    and id<>11
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it still gives me the same error: 'SQL Error(1093): You can't specify target table 'message' for update in FROM clause'.